# Why does TypedValue.applyDimension() scale differently than BitmapFactory.decodeResource()?

Tags: android

I have a 100x100 image and some coodinates that I want to place it at, which are to the same scale with the image. I load the image with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`, and it gets scaled to 133x133. But when I use `TypedValue.applyDimension()` with `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP` to scale my coordinates, I get a scaling factor of x2 rather than x1.33.

How can I ensure that my coordinates and image get scaled by the same amount?

Comment: In what generalized resource bucket is the source image located, and what kind of device are you testing on? An `hdpi` resource on an `xhdpi` device by any chance? In that case `BitmapFactory` probably takes into consideration the folder in which the resource is located (`hdpi` to `xhdpi` ratio is 6:8, or x1.33). `TypedValue` on the other hand could scale from the baseline, which is `mdpi`, and `mdpi` to `xhdpi` ratio is 4:8, or x2.

Comment: I have a galaxy nexus, which I believe is xhdpi. Because this project grew out of some older tutorials, though, my largest drawable folder is indeed hdpi. That may just be the issue; I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing on an xhdpi device, but I didn't have any xhdpi resources, so the `decodeResource()` was grabbing my hdpi resources and scaling up by 2/1.5=1.33.

The correct solution seems to be that you should specify your coordinates in the same scale as your mdpi resources, and ensure that you scale your alternate sized drawables with the same ratio that android expects, then use `TypedValue.applyDimension()` to scale your coordinates.